# How to check product delivery from pincode using end point API MAGENTO-2

Tags: magento2, rest-api, pincodes

I need one help. I need to know is there ant end point API available to check the delivery serviceability from pincode. User has its pincode as the input and need to check the  `delivery serviceability` of one product. I need the end point API for this.

Comment: https://devdocs.magento.com/codelinks/attributes.html#ShipmentRepositoryInterface

Comment: End point :: GET /V1/shipments

Comment: @AdityaShah : How i will pass the pincode in this end point ?

Comment: Using search criteria

Comment: @AdityaShah: Can you please give me one example with that end point ?

Comment: I used like `http://example.com/rest/V1/shipments?searchCriteria[filterGroups][][filters][][field]=postcode&searchCriteria[filterGroups][][filters][][value]=751010&searchCriteria[filterGroups][][filters][][conditionType]=en` and got error `{"message":"Internal Error. Details are available in Magento log file. Report ID: webapi-5c011e9b16fcf"}`.